# How to replace an existing symlink?

Tags: php

I need to replace php72(7.2 version) with php(5.6 version)

what I've tried:

```
ln -sf /usr/bin/php72 php
```

so the first path is the bin file of the php executionary file, and the second is the link name? should I set it to php? or what exactly should I put(a path to what?)

cause the command above didn't replaced the php after checking its version it was the same

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems correct.
Just check whether the existing link php is owned by you.
Also hope you have ensured that the file or directory "/usr/bin/php72" exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps with your files paths:

```
# which php
/usr/bin/php
# ls -l /usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
# cd /etc/alternatives/
# ls -lart php
php -> /usr/bin/php5.6
```

Check whether php7.2 exist:

```
# ls -l /usr/bin/php*
/usr/bin/php7.2
```

Then from folder /etc/alternatives/ execute the command with root:

```
# rm -f php && ln -s /usr/bin/php7.2 php
```

This  will remove the link php and on success execution will create new link pointing php7.2.

Check the result:

```
# ls -lart php
php -> /usr/bin/php7.2
```